# vscode extension how to add custom view below the treeviewItem like github copliot labs extenstion?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

like this

[image]

can we have api to achieve that effect? or use webView?

Comment: oof. [the extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.copilot) seems to not be open-source. I was interested in reading the sources.

Comment: use a `WebviewView` you have total control of what is rendered